# How to reference a struct instance method

Tags: rust

How can I reference a method from an instance instead of the full type.

It is easy that having any type that implements a function, you can access the method with `MyStruct::the_method`.

But how to do the same with an ***instance*** of it?

I got the following example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad1ab7ace04683940d2b64289f90d335)):

```rust
struct NumGen<N> {
    num: N
}


impl<N: Copy> NumGen<N> {
    fn new(n: N) -> Self {
        Self {
            num: n,
        }
    }

    fn get_num(&self) -> N {
        self.num
    }
}


fn print_num_from_other_func<F>(mut f: F) where F: FnMut() -> u32 {
    println!("{}", f());
}


fn main() {
    print_num_from_other_func(|| 10);
    let num_gen = NumGen::new(10);
    print_num_from_other_func(|| num_gen.get_num());
    // this part doesn't work
    // print_num_from_other_func(num_gen::get_num);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this does not work at all. `get_num(&self)` has an argument `&self`. You do not want the instance of this function but the instance of this function with `&self` bound to `num_gen. This is a new function and you create it just as you did (`|| num_gen.get_num()`). You can also first assign this function to a local variable and the use this one as argument (if you want an instance of the function).

Comment: @CoronA, yes, that is the thing, I want the function but bound to `self` already so it actually implements `FnMut() -> u32` (this means that it do not receive the self argument). The only way i found to did it was to wrapp it in a clousure

Comment: But this is nothing other than what you want. Also in Java and Javascript `num_gen::get_num` is just syntactical sugar for the corresponding closure (I am not completely certain, but it feels that there is no other way).

Comment: @CoronA, perfect, that is all I wanted to know. thanks!, Should we add it as an answer anyway?

Comment: @eggyal,yes indeed.